# Windows CreateFile Possible Error Codes

Tags: c++, c, windows, file-io

<strike>I'm playing around with abstracting Windows, Linux, and Mac File IO calls into macros (to avoid C runtime, so no `fopen`, `fclose`, etc...).  I've actually got quite a bit working but I've run into a stumbling block.</strike>

I'm trying to boil down all of the possible errors that could be thrown by each of these platforms into a subset of common ones: Not Found, Exists, Invalid Access, etc.

Linux is obviously well document, Mac even has the most common ones, but Windows does not specify which errors are thrown for its native File I/O functions.  We obviously need to use `GetLastError()`, but I could not find a reference to what the possible values would be.

### How about this?

I'm writing a Windows application and using the `CreatFile()` API.  I'd like to handle any errors as gracefully as I can, and perhaps recover from said error instead of telling the user "Crap! Can't do that."  But the MSDN docs don't list the possible error codes that could be generated.

Does anyone have a reference to the possible error codes that Windows File functions may generate, specifically (for now) `CreateFile()`?

Comment: There is no such list and there likely never will be. Why would you need to know this?

Comment: [The Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/) might have something.

Comment: This practice would seem common for C developers, because C language doesn't have proper exception mechanism.

Comment: I trust that you are checking the value retuned by `CreateFile` for `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` and not indiscriminately calling `GetLastError`.

Comment: By the way, you *do* know C++ have already done that? That is, made [abstract, platform independent, file handling functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the responses.  David: I tried to give as much detail as to why, and yes definitely checking for INVALID_FILE_HANDLE.

Comment: Why was C added as a tag? Do you want a C or a C++ solution?

Comment: @RedX: You do know that CreateFile itself is a macros, right? It resolves to either CreateFileA or CreateFileW. Same thing applies to pretty much any windows function that accepts TCHAR or LPTSTR. Sometimes there's a valid reason to wrap a function into macros.

Comment: Downvoters are down voting my decision to do this, not my question.
C was added because the WinAPI is C.

Comment: Joachim: MSDN was no help, I know how CreateFile is implemented. Point?

RedX: Not relevant

Comment: @random_acts: WinAPI is not "C", it can be used in C++. And people are downvoting you for the lack of research effort.

Comment: @SigTerm Yes i know they are macros.

Comment: Man, I thought it was a simple question... You guys are brutal. Coding police... @SigTerm  I've spent lots of effort researching this.  I don't understand your point that it can be used from C++, or the statement that it is not C, which it certainly is.

Comment: @random_acts: *"spent lots of effort researching this"* It implies that you were searching in the wrong place or didn't know where to look. For the future reference - all WinAPI documentation is on msdn. Find function page, and read links to related functions/types at the bottom of the page. If something isn't explicitly documented, assume worst-case scenario. I.e. if CreateFile doesn't list all possible error codes, assume that anything can happen. Also check Murphy's Law.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows supports installable file systems.  Microsoft cannot possibly predict what kind of errors a 3rd party file system driver is going to generate so does not make any attempt to promise a strict sub-set of possible error codes.

So yes, you really do have to use GetLastError().  The FormatMessage() function is available to generate a readable string for the error code.  In general, the user will get a decent error message that helps him diagnose the root cause.  It isn't quite specific enough to tell that an earthquake in Chile severed an undersea communication cable but it will certainly help him to start looking at networking problems for example.  You can use the CRT wrappers as well, but with the inevitable loss of specificity.  That might be a service call that you have to handle instead of the user's IT staff.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I appreciate a straight answer to my question.  I was afraid that this was the case, but was hoping against hope.  I'm giving you the answer for being civil and polite (rather than assuming I'm an idiot who hadn't checked the relevant documentation or googled like a maniac for an answer or search SO for related questions.)

Comment: @random_acts: "rather than assuming", you haven't mentioned what you tried, what you researched, and what you've found on the web. And by default people often assume worst-case scenario.

Comment: From your post, it sounds as if _installable file systems_ implies _cannot define error codes_. But the API developer in me says that it really is _Microsoft does not impose limitations on error codes_, not more, not less.

Answer (score 3):

> to avoid C runtime

You're reinventing the wheel. C runtime was created so people could write platform-independent programs that (theorietcally) would compile anywhere, as long as you aren't using something platform-specific.
Right now, you're doing the same thing.

I'd advise to stop doing that and either use standard C file function, or cross-platform framework that support several platform. You could use either Boost or Qt 4.

Regarding your question

> Does anyone have a reference to the possible error codes that Windows File functions may generate,

WinAPI documentation is available on MSDN and you should read it.
[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SystemErrorCodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Does anyone have a reference to the possible error codes that Windows File functions may generate

Because CreateFile doesn't only deal with "files" (it also works with directories, pipes, physical devices, etc), you should assume that it can generate any operating system code that exists. According to msdn, there are 16000 codes total. Moral of the story: if you want to generate human-readable message, use [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If documentation doesn't list possible error codes (for CreateFile), it automatically means, that CreateFile can produce any error code that exists.

Comment: I checked the WinAPI docs, no dice.  I even sifted through the first 500 error codes to see which might apply. I doubt sifting through the next 14500 would be more help.  Thanks though!

Comment: Fair point that CreateFile is used for more than files, this is very true.  I guess I was hoping for docs of some sort that would at least whittle down the possibilities from 16000 to say 500, and I could pick out the File related ones.

Comment: @random_acts: Nah. No such thing. Just use FormatMessage. I mean, even if you handled all codes that exist NOW, in the future version of windows they could add new ones. And that would break you program. Hans have a good point about installable file systems. So, no matter how you look at it, trying to find subset of codes to use might lead to some kind of disaster. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

As SigTerm stated, there's no definitive list of *system* error codes associated with CreateFile. Your best bet is searching for the keyword "ERROR" in the [CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)/[CreateFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) documentation.

Otherwise, there's always web search engine. A quick DuckDuckGo search of "CreateFile" and "Error" reveals a slew of errors and error codes

You should also consult Microsoft's lengthy lists of [System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes) and [Win32 Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d).

## Excerpts from CreateFileA/CreateFileW Documentation

#### param: `dwShareMode`

You cannot request a sharing mode that conflicts with the access mode that is specified in an existing request that has an open handle. `CreateFile` would fail and the `GetLastError` function would return `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32).

#### param: `dwCreationDisposition`

##### `CREATE_ALWAYS`

If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function *succeeds*, and last-error code is set to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (183).

##### `CREATE_NEW`

If the specified file exists, the function *fails* and the last-error code is set to `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` (80).

##### `OPEN_ALWAYS`

If the specified file exists, the function *succeeds* and the last-error code is set to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (183).

##### `OPEN_EXISTING`

If the specified file or device does not exist, the function *fails* and the last-error code is set to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2).

##### `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`

If the specified file does not exist, the function *fails* and the last-error code is set to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2).

### Files

If you call `CreateFile` on a file that is pending deletion as a result of a previous call to `DeleteFile`, the function fails. The operating system delays file deletion until all handles to the file are closed. `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

If `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are specified, `CreateFile` fails and sets the last error to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the file exists and has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` attribute. To avoid the error, specify the same attributes as the existing file.

When an application creates a file across a network, it is better to use GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE for dwDesiredAccess than to use GENERIC_WRITE alone. The resulting code is faster, because the redirector can use the cache manager and send fewer SMBs with more data. This combination also avoids an issue where writing to a file across a network can occasionally return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

### Consoles

If `lpFileName` is indeterminate "CON" and `dwDesiredAccess` is `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`, CreateFile fails; GetLastError returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

- "CON" and `GENERIC_READ` implies a console handle for input.
- "CON" and "GENERIC_WRITE` implies a console handle for output.

### Pipes

If the `CreateNamedPipe` function was not successfully called on the server prior to this operation, a pipe will not exist and `CreateFile` will fail with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

If there is at least one active pipe instance but there are no available listener pipes on the server, which means all pipe instances are currently connected, `CreateFile` fails with `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`.

## Various errors from across the internet

- `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` (1)
- `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2)
- `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3)
- `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5)
- `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE` (31) - A device attached to the system is not functioning. This can also occur when working with network devices e.g. virtual network adapters
- `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32) - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
- `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87) - "An application must meet certain requirements when working with files that are opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING: File access must begin at byte offsets within a file that are integer multiples of the volume sector size. File access must be for numbers of bytes that are integer multiples of the volume sector size. For example, if the sector size is 512 bytes, an application can request reads and writes of 512, 1024, 1536, or 2048 bytes, but not of 335, 981, or 7171 bytes. Buffer addresses for read and write operations should be sector aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory that are integer multiples of the volume sector size. Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced."
- `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` (120) - using P/Invoke and calling to coredll.dll for Windows Pocket PC
- `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (123)
- `ERROR_FILE_SYSTEM_VIRTUALIZATION_INVALID_OPERATION` (181)
- `ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE` (223)
- `ERROR_CONNECTION_COUNT_LIMIT` (1238)
- `ERROR_MUTUAL_AUTH_FAILED` (1397) - network auth e.g. serial COM port over Bluetooth
- `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES` (1450) - e.g. working with Serial Ports