# List of GetLastError() error codes for every winapi function

Tags: c, winapi, getlasterror

Is there a list that provides error codes that are returned by **given** winapi function through GetLastError() ? is there any official or unofficial resource that provides such documentation ?

for example winsock function documentation pages on MSDN provide table of possible WSAGetLastError() codes, while other winapi functions do not have such list for every possible error of given function and this is the exact problem addressed in this question, I am asking for similar documentation for every winapi function.

What I am **not** asking for:

- [List of winapi error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Advice on implementing error-handling or some library that deals with error-handling
- advice on usage of FormatMessage() and similar

EDIT: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249273/windows-createfile-possible-error-codes) question, it deals with one particular function (CreateFile) which seems to be exception because third party file systems can provide their own error codes, even if most functions fall under this case, there still should be most common/standard error codes

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such exhaustive list. Each function's documentation contains a partial listing of the error codes it uses. That's all you are guaranteed. It may set other error codes, or it may set none of them. You just have to check and see, after a function that promises to set an error code has failed.

Comment: @CodyGray some functions some of which are extensively used ones don't provide even partial listing

Comment: Then you have no guarantees about what error codes they set. You'd have to determine it by experimentation, and that would be fragile because it's subject to change on different versions of the OS. Why do you need this?

Comment: What about common errors that are not likely to change such as file doesn't exist, ran out of resources or not enough memory ?

Comment: The implementation of the functions can always change such that they do or do not set those errors. The error codes are just a guideline, primarily designed to help you in debugging and maybe to display to a user in an "Additional Information" section of an error message box. You aren't supposed to have exhaustive handling for all of them in your code. Any error conditions that are *expected* and should be handled will be listed in the MSDN documentation for that particular function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such list. In fact, there cannot be one, because there are API calls, that aren't even in control of the entire set of error codes they can return (consider, for example, [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx), where user-provided code sets the error code).

Some API calls provide a partial list of error codes they can return. On those cases it is part of the documented contract, and your code can be written to account for those error codes. Keep in mind, that those lists are usually never complete, so your code needs to be prepared to deal with other error codes as well.

In short, error handling needs to be implemented on a case-by-case basis. There are common patterns, but there is no single catch-all implementation.

Comment: I'd try and persuade anyone who thought they did have a complete list to handle 'other' anyway. It's very fragile to rely release-to-release on a final list of possible error codes. It's hard to imagine a performance overhead in additionally checking what is already a failure state.

Comment: that means only official error handling is throwing dialog box with "we are sorry for inconvenience [insert formatted message] please contact vendor" or "please check log file" ? then how can everyday programs with thousands and thousands different winapi calls like chrome, word, excel, photoshop and many more work without throwing no errors to user or 1-2 at max ? there MUST be some handling for example sleep(1000) if out of handles and etc, can you tell me how does _real world_ work ? which is outside of realm of clever 50 liner examples which are written with solely standard libraries

Comment: They check for errors without needing a list of all possible error codes. But that's not what you asked. You asked for a list of all possible error codes for each function. Do you want to know how to handle errors?

Comment: there is 15999 case switch after every call ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are greatly exaggerating the rate at which unexpected errors occur.  Most of the time when you make an API call, the only reason it could fail is that something has gone critically wrong with either your program or the operating system; and in that case, it doesn't matter what the error code is, since there's nothing you can realistically do about it anyway.  Your program should record the error code in case it helps in troubleshooting the problem, but that's it.

Comment: ... if your program is robust, this will only happen very very rarely.  The marginal benefit of attempting to recover from an unexpected error based on the error code is tiny, the effort involved would be huge even if you had the list you're asking for, and that's why real-world programs like Chrome, Word, Excel, and Photoshop don't bother.  At most, they'll attempt to ensure that the user's data is protected, and they are *not* likely to use the error code to decide how to go about doing so.

Comment: @BleedingAlice: So your real question is: How do I write solid code? That's fairly simple: By handling those errors you can meaningfully handle, and being prepared for all others you cannot. Knowing all possible error codes any given API call can trigger does not help here. You really should have asked a different question. If you are desperately looking for an answer, how *real world* programs implement error handling, check out the [Chromium source code](https://github.com/chromium/chromium).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such list. Even when the documentation for a specific function lists error codes that can be returned, that list is not exhaustive. You always need to cater for the eventuality of other codes being returned.